# How to disable Mat Radio button in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

If I use `disabled= true` property in the html than the mat radio button is disabling properly but if I have to disable some radio button through some functions I am setting disabled attribute through renderer like

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(this.matRadio.nativeElement, 'disabled', 'true');
```

which doesn't disabling the radio button. How should I disable some radio button through a function ?

Comment: What changeDetection strategy are you using?

Comment: Default one ... I am not changing any change detection strategy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be working. because you are updating using the Renderer disable css class might not be getting added.

Along with the the above function you need to add the disable class also

```js
this.renderer.setAttribute(this.matRadio.nativeElement, 'disabled', 'true');
this.renderer.addClass(this.matRadio.nativeElement, 'mat-radio-disabled')
```

Please try this

Comment: It is applying the disabled class and style but the radio button isn't actually disabled i can still click it

Comment: using `this.matRadio` variable which one you are referring in html using @ViewChild?
Can you show?

Comment: `<mat-radio-button #matRadio></mat-radio-button>` ... I am actually using viewChildren to get all the mat radio buttons which have #matRadio reference.. And then using `this.renderer.setAttribute(this.matRadio.toArray()[index].nativeElement, 'disabled', 'true')` and setting the class also

Comment: Why cant you use `@ViewChildren('matRadio') matRadio: QueryList<MatRadioButton>;` and you can use `this.matRadio.toArray().forEach( radio => radio.disabled = true)`;.

Comment: Where are you writing `this.matRadio.toArray().forEach( radio => radio.disabled = true)` Is it inside `ngOnInit()`?

Comment: I am writing `this.matRadio.toArray()[index].nativeElement.disabled = true` inside a function so when the function called this particular index's radio will be disabled...and i am calling the function in click not in ngOnInit lifycyclehook

Comment: if you are using `@ViewChildren('matRadio') matRadio: QueryList<MatRadioButton>;`
then go for `this.matRadio.toArray().forEach( radio => radio.disabled = true)`
Is there any reason you strictly use renderer?

Comment: Ok thanks that working i was reading the viewChildren as normal ElementRef instead of MatRadioButton ...thats why it was not working

Answer (score 0):

First get element and then use element.setAttribute("disabled","true")

Answer (score 0):

You can use reactive forms:

Disabled when creating the FormControl:

```
formControl = new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
```

Disable programatically:

```
this.formControl.disable();
```

Comment: not using formcontrol...just simple radio button